# Is it possible to make compiler emit diagnostics on default-initialized member?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Consider simple C++ code:

```
class X {
  int a_, b_;
public:
  X(int a) : a_(a) {} // b not mentioned in intializer list
  int get_sum() { return a_ + b_; }
};

int foo () {
  X x(2); // x.b_ is indetermined
  return x.get_sum(); // returns garbage
}
```

In this snippet, `x.b_` is [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to indeterminate value. I tried gcc 7.2 and clang 5.1 and no one warned me about this simple case.

For example clang:

```
clang++ init.cc -S -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++
```

Compiles silently.

It is very inconvenient, and, I think, it is very simple for clang to reason about such things.

Am I missing some obvious way to make compiler report such cases? Or may be I am wrong and `x.b_` is properly initialized?

Comment: If you pass `-fsanitize=address,undefined` it should at least be caught at runtime. Maybe clang-tidy or cppcheck can detect it statically.